# Erro:Build Solution - Visual Studion

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-8, xaml

Ao tentar fazer o Build da solução o VS2013 apresenta o seguinte erro:

*Error 1; Could not copy the file "obj/Debug/Win8AppBoX.exe" because it was not found.*

**Notei que o arquivo .exe é excluído da pasta no momento do build.**

link para download: https://www.sendspace.com/file/66bb15

Comment: está a correr o VS como admin?

Answer (score 1):

Algo apagou o arquivo logo após ter sido criado, geralmente esse comportamento é apresentado pelo Antivírus que detectou o arquivo como sendo uma ameaça.

Comment: Obrigado Pela resposta... 
Isso é uma possibilidade, mas acontece que não tenho antivírus instalado.